# RefineryCMS - remove default page parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I want to remove the **side_body** section on each page in RefineryCMS.

The guide advises that you can [change page parts](http://refinerycms.com/guides/changing-page-parts) by going into `config/initializers/refinery/pages.rb` and altering the settings:

So I have changed:

```
config.default_parts = [“Body”, “Side Body”]
```

to:

```
config.default_parts = [“Body”]
```

I have restarted my server, but my side_body section still appears. Can the side_body be removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just a guess, but I believe that it only appears on already existing pages. If you create a new page, you should only see the `Body`-tag. At least this was the behavior in Refinery 1.0.8.

To remove the `Side Body` from already existing pages, you will have to make the pageparts editable. I think you can achieve this by setting `config.new_page_parts => true`. After that, when you edit the page, you should be able to see a (+), a (-) and a (reorder)-sign right above the editor.